# Forward fill on custom value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking to perform forward fill on some dataframe columns.
the `ffill` method replaces missing values or NaN with the previous filled value.
In my case, I would  like to perform a forward fill, with the difference that I don't want to do that on Nan but for a specific value (say "*").

Here's an example

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np

d = [{"a":1, "b":10},
     {"a":2, "b":"*"},
     {"a":3, "b":"*"},
     {"a":4, "b":"*"},
     {"a":np.nan, "b":50},
     {"a":6, "b":60},
     {"a":7, "b":70}]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

with `df` being

```
     a   b
0  1.0  10
1  2.0   *
2  3.0   *
3  4.0   *
4  NaN  50
5  6.0  60
6  7.0  70
```

The expected result should be

```
     a   b
0  1.0  10
1  2.0  10
2  3.0  10
3  4.0  10
4  NaN  50
5  6.0  60
6  7.0  70
```

If replacing "*" by `np.nan` then `ffill`, that would cause to apply `ffill` to column `a`.

Since my data has hundreds of columns, I was wondering if there is a more efficient way than looping over all columns, check if it countains "*", then replace and ffill.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`df.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with [`df.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) with [`df.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html)

```
df.mask(df.isin(['*']),df.replace('*',np.nan).ffill())

     a   b
0  1.0  10
1  2.0  10
2  3.0  10
3  4.0  10
4  NaN  50
5  6.0  60
6  7.0  70
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you're going in the right direction, but here's a complete solution. What I'm doing is 'marking' the original NaN values, then replacing "*" with NaN, using `ffill`, and then putting the original NaN values back.

```
df = df.replace(np.NaN, "<special>").replace("*", np.NaN).ffill().replace("<special>", np.NaN)
```

output:

```
     a     b
0  1.0  10.0
1  2.0  10.0
2  3.0  10.0
3  4.0  10.0
4  NaN  50.0
5  6.0  60.0
6  7.0  70.0
```

And here's an alternative solution that does the same thing, without the 'special' marking:

```
original_nan = df.isna()
df = df.replace("*", np.NaN).ffill()
df[original_nan] = np.NaN
```